# What is wrong is here?

Tags: django, python-3.x

## Exception:

> File "/Users/user/Desktop/Dp1/simplesocial/groups/views.py", line 24
>       `messages.warning(self.request=,('Warning already a member!'))`
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin)
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from groups.models import Group,GroupMember
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name','description')
    model = Group
class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group
class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group
class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request=,('Warning already a member!'))
        else:
            messages.success(self.request,'You are now a member!')
        return super().get(request,*args,**kwargs)
class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            membership = models.GroupMember.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,group__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).get()
        except models.GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request,'Sorry you are not in this group!')
        else:
            membership.delete()
            messages.success(self.request,'You have left the group!')
        return super().get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: As the error message clearly shows, you have a typo in that line - an unnecessary `=`.

Comment: `messages.warning(self.request,('Warning already a member!'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
        messages.warning(self.request,'Warning already a member!')
```

Answer (score 0):

here bug fixed

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (LoginRequiredMixin,PermissionRequiredMixin)
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from groups.models import Group,GroupMember
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.
class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name','description')
    model = Group
class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group
class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
    model = Group
class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request,('Warning already a member!'))
        else:
            messages.success(self.request,'You are now a member!')
        return super().get(request,*args,**kwargs)
class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse('groups:single',kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')})
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            membership = models.GroupMember.objects.filter(user=self.request.user,group__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).get()
        except models.GroupMember.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request,'Sorry you are not in this group!')
        else:
            membership.delete()
            messages.success(self.request,'You have left the group!')
        return super().get(request,*args,**kwargs)
```